# Options to report and view a possible phishing script hosted under scripts.google.com

Tags: google-apps-script

Received an email from someone claiming to be Amazon support that links to a script.google.com/macros page. I visiting it on Android without realizing what it was and wanted to see if there was a place to report the script and view what information it gathered.

I spent a good 30 minutes trying to find a place in google to get support on this issue and could not find any other than asking technical support here so I figured I would try making a post.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try this page:

> "Thank you for helping us keep the web safe from phishing sites. If you
> believe you've encountered a page designed to look like another page
> in an attempt to steal users' personal information, please complete
> the form below to report the page to the Google Safe Browsing team."

https://safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/report_phish/?hl=en